# ChromeDriverでのスクレイピング時に作成される/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.XXXXX/internal.zipのパスを固定したい

Tags: web-scraping, chromedriver

Linux(RedHat)上のSelenium+ChromeDriverでスクレイピングしていますが、

```
/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.XXXXX/internal.zip
（xxxxxはランダム文字列で起動のたびに異なる）
```

のようなファイルが作成されます。
このファイルが作成されるパスを特定のディレクトリに変更したいです。

**変更したい背景**
上記ファイルがウィルススキャンソフト（SophosAntivirus　以後SAV）のオンアクセススキャンの対象になり、稀にスキャンしようとするが既に削除されているためエラーとなっています。
SAVの仕様として正規表現を含むパスの除外は一応は可能なものの、talpaドライバーを一度経由したのちに、除外判断されるため、talpaドライバでの処理中に削除されるとエラーになってしまいます。
そのため、固定パスの除外されたディレクトリ配下に下記ファイルの出力先を変更したいと考えています。

**補足**
キャッシュやユーザデータも同様にランダム文字を含むディレクトリに出力されますが、以下オプションで固定化できております。

```
--user-data-dir=固定パス
--disk-cache-dir=固定パス
```

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
環境変数TMPDIRを指定する事でその配下に作成される事を確認しました。
これにより固定パスでの除外ができました。
ありがとうございました。